# How to detect store change in component after dispatch NgRx Unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-store

After changing the the state from 'light' to 'dark' it's not gonna change it in component. It will keep the state as 'light' even though I have dispatched an action which is gonna change it to dark.
Is there a way to detect it in component?

Here is the unit test file

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let compiled: HTMLElement;
  let store: MockStore;

  const initialState = {
    theme: fromTheme.initialState,
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [AppRoutingModule],
      providers: [provideMockStore({ initialState })],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    store = TestBed.get<MockStore>(MockStore);
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should have a class with theme', () => {
    expect(compiled.classList.contains('light')).toBeTrue();

    store.dispatch(fromTheme.changeTheme({ payload: 'dark' }));

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(compiled.classList.contains('dark')).toBeTrue();
  });
});
```

Here is the component file

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  host: {
    '[class.light]': 'theme === "light"',
    '[class.dark]': 'theme === "dark"',
  },
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  theme: ThemeType = 'light';

  themeSubscription: Subscription | null = null;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppStore>,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.themeSubscription = this.store.select(selectTheme).subscribe((themeState) => {
      this.theme = themeState.theme;

      if (!themeState.isChanged) {
        const preferredTheme = getPreferredTheme();

        this.store.dispatch(changeTheme({ payload: preferredTheme }));
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.themeSubscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need to provide a mock store, instead of that, we can provide the real store like this

```
let store: Store<AppStore>;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [AppRoutingModule, StoreModule.forRoot(appReducer)],
  });

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  store = TestBed.get<Store>(Store);
});
```

Then the component will listen for changes in this store, and the dispatch will work.

Test Examples:

```
it('should have a class with theme', () => {
  store.select(fromTheme.selectTheme)
    .subscribe((themeState) => {
      expect(compiled.classList.contains(themeState.theme)).toBeTrue();
    });
});
```

---

```
it('should be able to dispatch the changeTheme', () => {
  const newTheme = 'dark';

  store.dispatch(fromTheme.changeTheme({ payload: newTheme }));

  expect(compiled.classList.contains(newTheme)).toBeTrue();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`provideMockStore` doesn't run the reducers/effects.
Because a reducer is a pure function it's also easier to just test the reducer via the reducer method. This makes your tests also faster because you don't need the TestBed/Setup/Component.

For an example see https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/testing-an-ngrx-project#reducers

If you need to test the component then you need to set the state manually/override the selector, see https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-mock-selectors for an example.

Or, don't use the mockstore and rely on the real impementation.